# Add a Triangle to denote selected nav item in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site that I've created with Bootstrap. At the top of my site, I have two rows for navigation. The code for those rows looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-info horizontal-nav">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav list-inline">
    <li><a href="/" class="btn btn-basic">home</a></li>
    <li class="selected"><a href="/about" class="btn btn-basic">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact" class="btn btn-basic">contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="navbar horizontal-nav navbar-light bg-faded">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav list-inline">
    <li><a href="/about/us" class="btn btn-basic">intro</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about/service" class="btn btn-basic">service</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

When this renders, it looks something like this:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| home   about   contact                |
+---------------------------------------+
| intro   service                       |
+---------------------------------------+
```

I'm trying to show a triangle for a selected item. So that way the user knows where they are at. In essence, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| home   about   contact                |
+----------^----------------------------+
| intro   service                       |
+------------^--------------------------+
```

How do I do that with CSS / Bootstrap? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use content after to create the shape and then add it to the active Bootstrap state. See example.

```css
.navbar.navbar-dark,
.navbar.navbar-light {
  height: 60px;
}
nav.navbar .navbar-nav li.nav-item.active:after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -15px;
  left: 50%;
  top: -20px;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<hr>
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-info">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>

      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Intro <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. My triangles are always centered in the middle of the screen. I think it has to do with the fact that I've wrapped your entire block in a `<div class="container">`, but I'm not sure. Why would the triangles be centered in the middle of the screen overtime instead of in the middle of the `li`.

Comment: Can you post/update the code in your question to reflect this with any CSS you've customized?

Comment: I found the reason. However, I do not have a solution yet. I took your code and I found the difference. Your code works with Bootstrap 3.3.5. I'm working with Bootstrap 4. When I use Bootstrap 4 with your code snippet, I run into the same problem that I reported. I'm not sure if its a bug in Bootstrap 4 or an intended change.